# How mopub manages its macros?

Tags: javascript, android, mopub

i'm developing an app that works with a tag, like mopub does. But i can't found how mopub manages his macros. In other words, my app will read a JavaScript tag and will process the tag in the app. For this reason i need help to know how does mopub do for manage the macros.

Comment: Please post your code or show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MoPub Macros
>
> MoPub supports the following macros for a publisher’s 3rd party ad
>   tags and trackers:
>
> - Click URL (Unescaped):  %%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%
> - Click URL (Escaped):  %%CLICK_URL_ESC%%
> - Cache Buster (Generates a random number): %%CACHEBUSTER%%
> - Ad Group ID: %eaid!
> - Creative ID: %ecid!
> - Destination URL: %%DEST_URL%%
> - Destination URL (Escaped): %%DEST_URL_ESC%%
> - Destination URL (Double Escaped): %%DEST_URL_ESC_ESC%%
> - IDFA, SHA1 Hashed Android ID, or Android Advertising ID (if Google    Play Services is integrated): %eudid!
> - Keywords: %%KEYWORDS%%
> - Specific Key Value: %%KEYWORD:[key]%% (replace [key] with the    parameter you want to return the value for)
> - Latitude: %%LATITUDE%%
> - Longitude: %%LONGITUDE%%
>
> Notes about Macros:
>
> If you’re passing over key value pairs, you can set a macro to return
>   the value for a particular key. e.g. If you’re passing over
>   “gender:male,age:24” as your keywords, you can use the %%KEYWORD:age%%
>   macro to pass the age into your ad. %%KEYWORD:age%% will be replaced
>   with 24
>
> If you are using a mobile web tag, you can manually pass up UDID
>   through the UDID macro if it is being passed from another server (ie.
>   DFP) Cachebusters are noted by &ord= parameters.
>
> If your HTML ad is using an anchor tag () or window.location
>   redirect, our SDK automatically tracks clicks The %%CACHEBUSTER%%
>   macro returns unix timestamp in milliseconds   If you are using mobile
>   web, your tag can support click tracking if you prepend the click
>   tracker.  To add click pending to a MoPub mobile web tag use the
>   following setup:
>
> ```
> <script type=”text/javascript”>// <![CDATA[
> var mopub_ad_unit=’AD UNIT ID’;
>
> //Be sure to set these to the size of your adunit
> var mopub_ad_width=320; //optional
> var mopub_ad_height=50; //optional
> var mopub_click_prepend=’[CLICK_PREPEND_MACRO]’;
>
> //Use custom keywords appropriate for your mobile webpage
> //var mopub_keywords= “custom keywords”; //optional
> // ]]></script>
> <script src=”http://ads.mopub.com/js/client/mopub.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
> ```

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/orders-line-items/macros